# What is this Ribbon control called?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

What are the following types of buttons called? I'm trying to replicate the Windows 7 WordPad application.

[image]

I tried using a RibbonButton, but that doesn't have the same style at all.

I'm using WPF and C#, in .NET 4.5 beta, which has the Ribbon interface included as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RibbonControlGroup` and add `RibbonButton`s to it.